# How can I reduce the surface tension to achieve realistic 1:43.5 scale waves etc

Tags: water, surface-tension

I want to achieve realistic flowing water instead of using polymers which produce static water. Ideally using a small wave making device to represent the sea.

Comment: Liquid soap reduces the surface tension of water.  Start off with a very small amount, and use trial-and-error to find the concentration that produces the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

By adding surfactants, you can scale back the surface tension of water (78 dyne-cm) to a minimum of a bit less than half this value (~35 dyne-cm), but not much lower than that. I do not know if this scaling range would be broad enough for your application. If you require something lower, you'll have to resort to a different liquid.